# Eclipse RCP: getting the default perspective switcher button via id from SWTBot

Tags: eclipse-rcp, swtbot

In an Eclipse 3.7 RCP app, I would like to get the Default perspective switcher button via id for SWTBot/unit testing purposes to get around this:

```
assertNotNull("PerspectiveBar not visisble", bot.toolbarButtonWithTooltip("Perspektive öffnen"));
```

How do I find out the id of the button to be able to use

```
assertNotNull("PerspectiveBar not visisble", bot.toolbarButtonWithId("somekey", "someid"));
```

Or: is there a better (internationalization-independent) way to do this, may setting key/id of this button by myself?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find any widget with SWTBot by an id,
you have to set the id against key "org.eclipse.swtbot.widget.key".

```
widget.setData("org.eclipse.swtbot.widget.key", "my.widget.id");
```

Now you can get the widget like below

```
bot.widget(withId("my.widget.id"));
```

For your case it will be

```
bot.toolbarButtonWithId("someid");
```

But before that you must ensure you set the id against the key mentioned above.